# how to convert a html based SVG tag attribute to REACTJS based SVG tag attribute

Tags: html, reactjs, svg

I have came across a problem while developing my project.

I have fetched an API endpoint and the response send from it is a SVG image and it was in html format. Till now no problem but when I am trying to use it in REACTJS , I don't know how to convert the response html SVG data to REACTJS based SVG data.